# When loading data in Rstudio getting error "ReadItem: unknown type 161, perhaps written by later version of R"?

Tags: r

When I am trying to load a clean data in Rstudio, file name called salesClean.RData, I am getting error.

Error message is: `ReadItem: unknown type 161, perhaps written by later version of R`

Screenshot of error message:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Well, the obvious question: are you using the latest version of R?

Comment: @marat i am using the latest version of Rstudio. Well,any productive answer could be nice.

Comment: iPlease [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

**Simple Solution:**

Try to use the tool *Load Workspace*. It allows you to select the Rds file and load it into memory.

**Best Solution:**

In some cases you do need to load the file programatically. In these situations you will probably prefer get your R up to date. You can do this by running the code:

```
install.packages("installr")
require(installr)
updateR()
```

Also, you can update your installed packages in RStudio on *Tools > Check for packages updates.*

Comment: This only works on windows. 
Try : 
install.packages("ropenblas")
ropenblas::rcompiler()
for linux users

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using the latest version not only of Rstudio, but R as well. Try `sessionInfo()` command, it should say that you have R version 3.1.2.

Comment: well,my Rstudio`s version was 3.1.1 but i updated it in R version 3.1.2 & R as well But still showing the same problem!

Comment: Error: ReadItem: unknown type 161, perhaps written by later version of R.

Comment: any chance that the file is corrupted?

Comment: file is not corrupted, i am sure about this.

Comment: Could you try it in bare `R` console?

Comment: I did n`t get it.what do you want to say ?I tried it in RStudio & RGui both!

Comment: Yes, I meant RGui. I think I'm running out of ideas... Btw is that possible that your .Rdata file was generated in some modified version of R e.g. Revolution?

Comment: I am also! would please just check on your Rstudio or RGui that this data set can be load...Data set dload link : 

[My Data Set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cyfleqpka3lfz2k/salesClean.RData?dl=0)

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work for me too. From the source code of R, I found that the problem is that your data set is of unknown type. It could happen in the case the .Rdata file was saved with a modified version of R. I guess that another reason could be that you might need to load some R library before trying to load the data set.

Comment: I loaded the all the necessary library & packages.

I have data set called sales.RData. By modifying it i somehow generate the salesClean.RData, may be you are right! Because of modified version of R it couldn`t be opened but it should to be open.

Comment: By the way, the binary format of .Rdata is not very complicated (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html, http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html), so if you do need to extract the data from that file, you might write your own reader of the .Rdata format. Alternatively, you might edit the file serialize.c and recompile R.

Comment: i am searching another thing.I think you might help me..did you work with weka data mining software ?

my processor told me to search for different algorithm that weka use internally...is that any way any how..i can manage the java codes of weka for different algorithm like naive bayes,id3,svm,jr8.you know weka produce different clustering & regression others things by clicking but i need to change this algorithm and somehow make my own algorithm using this algorithm.

Comment: I used the `RWeka` package once, but I didn't have a chance to gain much experience in this area. You might want to ask a new question at SO on this topic.

Comment: I got the same error in the following situation: I wrote an RDS file on a windows machine (R 3.1.2) and uploaded it on Github and downloaded it again using download.file() in R. Then I get the above error on my windows machine. Interestingly, I do not get an error if I download the file via the browser. Also I do not get any errors in any situation if I use my mac with R 3.2.2. Maybe somebody can make sense of this ...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, finally I found it's because the hard disk under my root is full. I freed some disk memory and re-saved the `.RDdata` file, the `load` works again.

Answer (score 0):

For me, had a very similar experience to @CcMango, though for me it was because I had run out of session memory. I restarted my Rstudio session with fresh memory and loaded fewer files and that solved it. For similar issues, I've had luck rewriting in batches or querying from other sources too.