# What's the reason that readRDS doesn't seem to work in Windows?

Tags: r, windows, git, rds, git-lfs

I'm trying to make the my code portable to Windows and realized that even though I use `file.path` to create paths still the `readRDS` function won't work, for example:

```
file.exists('C:/temp/HarvardX-Skillability/data/rds/Users.rds')
> TRUE
readRDS('C:/temp/HarvardX-Skillability/data/rds/Users.rds')
> Error in readRDS("C:/temp/HarvardX-Skillability/data/rds/Users.rds") : 
  error reading from connection
```

I also tried:

```
 file.exists('data/rds/Users.rds')
 > TRUE
 readRDS('data/rds/Users.rds')
 > Error in readRDS("data/rds/Users.rds") : error reading from connection
```

Why is that? and how can I fix it? In Ubuntu 18.04 works perfectly ...

Comment: How was the rds file created? Was it created on a different operating system? How did you copy it to the windows machine? Often things can get messed up when people transfer binary files as text files between operating systems.

Comment: Ah yes the file was created in Ubuntu 18.04, why they are not portable? :(

Comment: They are portable if you transfer them correctly. Do the files have the same md5sum at the moment? Can you check `tools::md5sum(Users.rds")` on both the windows machine and Ubuntu machine to make sure it was transferred correctly?

Comment: The file was created in Ubuntu with R 3.6.0 and I'm attempting to open from Windows and R 3.5.x would that be an issue?

Comment: Unlikely. That should be fine. Again, I think the problem is that the file was not copied over correctly.

Comment: What do you mean with "transfer" them correctly? what do you mean with correctly exactly? the saveRDS function doesn't have any parameters for portability ...

Comment: How are you getting the file from the Ubuntu computer to the windows computer? Are you using ftp? scp? a network file system? emailing it yourself?

Comment: they are in a repo in GitHub https://github.com/bravegag/HarvardX-Skillability/tree/master/data/rds

Comment: Attempting to open the smallest one `Tags.rds` produces a more informative error: `ReadItem: unknown type 27, perhaps written by later version of R`

Comment: According to the release notes, 3.6 should be compatible with 3.5: "Serialization format version 3 becomes the default for serialization and saving of the workspace (save(), serialize(), saveRDS(), compiler::cmpfile()). Serialized data in format 3 cannot be read by versions of R prior to version 3.5.0. Serialization format version 2 is still supported and can be selected by version = 2 in the save/serialization functions."  Did you check the md5sums yet? It's possible that when checking out the file git interprets the file as a text file and attempts to change line endings.

Comment: can you confirm that you can read it on the original machine/OS? Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155563/when-loading-data-in-rstudio-getting-error-readitem-unknown-type-161-perhaps) reported a problem due to a full hard drive/corrupted file.

Comment: I tried again with a fresh Windows R 3.6.x and doesn't work :( I will boot in Ubuntu but I am 100% positive it all works in Ubuntu. Thank you so much for your help :) I have more than 200GB free I have np with space.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the repo URL to your question ...

Comment: The `*.rds filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text` line in your `.gitattributes` looks troublesome since rds files are not text files. This all seems to be a git problem, not an R problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit to the OP was something really unexpected, I also didn't provide the information for it because I couldn't suspect this was the issue.

The problem was those files were being downloaded automatically using `download.file(url, filePath, extra="L")` and in Windows this is known to cause issues with binary files that are not the expected ones. This is why the rds files were unrecognizable.

I found out while building exception handling recovery code that was looking to download the same files from a Dropbox folder and then came to the same issue, therefore it wasn't because of Git LFS.

The OP solution was to add the argument `download.file(..., mode="wb")`.

See the question [R trouble unzipping file under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892505/r-trouble-unzipping-file-under-windows)

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be with *downloading*/cloning the files from GitHub. After running `git clone` on [your repository](https://github.com/bravegag/HarvardX-Skillability/), when I open my local copy of `Tags.rds` in a text editor I see this:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:b4a2cb3775126a3895e9533ef9ef4ad786b2021cfd1660b07028fbef85b025bb
size 641098
```

(this is the entire contents of the file). Furthermore, running `file Tags.rds` (in a Terminal on MacOS) reports `Tags.rds: ASCII text`. (All of the `.rds` files are like this.)

The GitHub web interface confirms that your files are OK on the repo:

[image]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159392/git-only-clones-sha-for-lfs-files-on-gitlab-ci) looks related.  After installing Git LFS and running `git lfs pull`, I get the full file downloaded (and `readRDS()` seems to work fine).

Comment: They are managed by `git-lfs` maybe could be related to that. I am 100% positive that it works from Ubuntu. The issue is opening from Windows.

Comment: Ok I will check ... need to reboot first :)

Comment: PS I want to give myself a bounty for figuring this out :-)

Comment: thank you so much! You've got me cold sweating when you suggested that the data files were corrupt ... deadline is in 2 days and those take many hours to generate using the `create_dataset.r` script ... I would really give you the bounty but since you almost got me a heart attack, and as compensation I will keep the bounty :D

Comment: I tested doing the following in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04), clone the project, then delete the rds files and run a function that automatically downloads the file from GitHub and it works perfectly. I have no idea why downloading it from Windows in exactly the same way it doesn't work.